# Google play account queries

Tags: android, google-play

Can I get the user information from my developer account in googleplay, i.e, who is downloading my application? I need to track all user details like phone number and the account details from where the user is installing the apk.

Comment: you can achieve this by implementing `google analytic` in your app.

Comment: Hii, Thanks for the reply. But my question is is there any section in the admin panel of my developer account that I can see the downloaded logs?